# How to get link to redirect to expo app during development

Tags: expo

How to get link to redirect to expo app during development?

I have a react native expo app. During development started with `èxpo start`. Now I like to use OAuth 2.0 authentication. Therefor I need a redirect URL.

My `app.json` looks like:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "myapp",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "slug": "myapp",
    "privacy": "public",
```

There is a documentation for linking to the app, but it's not clear to me which link to use during development to get redirected to the app launched in expo. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/#linking-to-your-app

I think `myapp://` is wrong because the app is still in development using `expo start` and not deployed as apk as standalone app.

Using `https://auth.expo.io/@myuser/myapp` resulted in:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the right link value at runtime :

```
Linking.makeUrl()
```

will resolve dynamicly according to running environment: dev, standalone app...

---

Note : Linking from expo-linking does have this method, but Linking from react-native does not.

Comment: `Linking` doesn't include a function called: `makeUrl()`

Comment: @BiskremMuhammad - `Linking` from `expo-linking` does, `Linking` from `react-native` does not ;)

Answer (score 7):

Linking.createURL() is available in expo-linking@2.0.1 and higher. If you are using an older version, use Linking.makeUrl() instead.

Answer (score 1):

In the newer versions of Expo Go, this feature works for me

```
 const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      scopes: [],
      redirectUri: Linking.createURL(),
    },
    discovery
  );
```

the Authorization callback URL in the github is the response of `Linking.createURL()`